# Fatal Error: Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk' not found

Tags: php, laravel, queue

On my API I wanted to change queue drivers. I wanted to switch from Beanstalkd to Redis.

So in my `composer.json` I changed my dependencies `"pda/pheanstalk": "^3.0"` to `"predis/predis": "~1.0"`. Then I went to Laravel Forge, added a new Queue Worker which looks like this:

[image: Queue workers]

I updated my `.env` file: `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis` and ran `composer update`. After that I tried to fire a notification (with email), the notification implements the `ShouldQueue` interface and uses the `Queueable` trait. The notification was send with success (over the queue as well).

At that moment I was happy, but wait... I check my Sentry issues and saw the following error:

> Fatal Error: Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk' not found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/**[BeanstalkdConnector.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/BeanstalkdConnector.php#L21)** in connect at line 21.

At this moment the bug/issues occurs around 200 times a minute.

What I tried:

1. Remove all failed jobs from queue
2. Restart the server
3. Even installing the `pda/pheanstalk` package over composer again.

So at the moment I've the `pda/pheanstalk` installed but don't have the beanstalkd queue worker running and I'm still getting the `Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk' not found` error.

My best guess is that when I removed the beanstalkd queue worker and removed the package with composer, their was a job running in the queue worker and now it's retrying that job over and over. But of course I could be totally wrong.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

**EDIT**

I've now deleted my site from Forge, checked if the code was deleted. In Sentry the error is still being logged.. The project doesn't even exists on the server anymore.

Comment: try restarting all your workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you havent restarted the queue to use the new settings?

Log into the server and run `php artisan queue:restart`

The other thing - did you have Supervisor or something already running the older queue config? If so - that could be restarting the older queue.

Comment: I'm using a dev and staging site as well. I forgot to restart the queue with the correct settings their. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As official laravel documentation, Please install the latest version of Beanstalkd

```
Beanstalkd: pda/pheanstalk ~4.0
```

For more info, Please check this
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#other-driver-prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Did you register `Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk` within your `config/app.php` file?

Usually that's the case, Laravel won't see any dependencies that were not registered.

Inside of array containing configuration for your app, find `providers', and put namespace of given class inside that array.

Comment: `Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk` is not an Laravel package, but a PHP package. It doesn't have a Service Provider. So putting the class in the `providers` array, wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @DeesOomens that doesn't matter. if you add it to `providers` array the application will attempt to look for this class and use it. Laravel doesn't know if it's a stand-alone lib or not

Comment: @vladko It does matter... [Pheanstalk](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk) doesn't have a service provider.

Comment: @DeesOomens try to add any random class that doesn't exist in `vendors` and see what happens... like `FakeProvider\FakeClass\SomeThing::class`,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you that you remove any references to this class in `conig/app.php` as well as run `composer dump-autoload`.

You may want to do a global search for this class in your app to make sure it's gone. Lastly, delete the vendor folder, if it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

Install pheanstalk as a dependency with composer:

> composer require pda/pheanstalk

In PHP file

> use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;